# npm command not working when trying to run

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

This is the error is get when i try to run 'npm run dev'

```
> portfolio@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

/home/aksh/Visual Studio Code/Web Dev/portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/lib/picocolors.js:134
const { env, stdout } = ((_globalThis = globalThis) == null ? void 0 : _globalThis.process) ?? {};
                                                                                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at Module.mod.require (/home/aksh/Visual Studio Code/Web Dev/portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:65:28)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/aksh/Visual Studio Code/Web Dev/portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/build/output/log.js:55:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: What's your node version?

Answer (score 0):

It most likely is your node version that doesn't compile the file. You should be fine by upgrating your node version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).